# Postgre COPY BeginBinaryExport While loop

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using C# Npgsql and am trying to export data from Postgres using the COPY command. The below query will return 100+ rows. I would like to read the results out using a while loop just like you would do with NpgsqlDataReader.

The documentation on http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html keeps throwing errors when I try to get a second row of results (second StartRow()). 
Notes: Running second StartRow() returns following error message below:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Unknown message code: 0

using (NpgsqlBinaryExporter reader = conn.BeginBinaryExport("COPY tableName(colONE, colTWO) TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)"))
            {
                reader.StartRow();
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<string>());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<int>(NpgsqlDbType.Smallint));

                reader.StartRow(); //### <== ERROR HERE ###
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<string>());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<int>(NpgsqlDbType.Smallint));
            }
```

How do I read out **ALL** the rows in a WHILE loop or output in one shot?

Comment: You need to post a real code sample, not pseudocode, for anyone to understand what's wrong - the code as written is the sample works well.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Cleaned up the explanation with real code. I'm still getting the error when running the code sample from the documentation

Comment: Can you please post the schema for your table, with the exact PostgreSQL data types? It's very probably a type mismatch, i.e. you're trying to read `NpgsqlDbType.Smallint` while your table has another type.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly something like this might help:

```
using (NpgsqlBinaryExporter reader = conn.BeginBinaryExport("COPY tableName(colONE, colTWO) TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)"))
        {
            while(reader.StartRow() > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<string>());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Read<int>(NpgsqlDbType.Smallint));
            }
        }
```

This should read all the data from the table, and it solved my similar issue. I am still looking at ways of improving the performance, so let me know if you have any ideas.